# JavaFX draw Shape on Tab

Tags: javafx, shapes

I have a JavaFX-TabPane where I put a Button as the tab-selector. So I can draw shapes on the button.
Everything is fine when I draw a simple Polygon like this:

```
    _______
   /       /
  /_______/
```

But I want to have a Polygon like that:

```
    _______
   /       /
  /_______/_
```

When I try this with 5 corner coordinates only my first example is being drawn.
What do I need to change so that the line at the bottom will be drawn?
Is it possible with a polygon? Or do I need to use something else?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Tab.setGraphic(polygon)?

Comment: Yes I tried that. But still the bottom right line is not drawn.